# Ajax asynchronous - how to avoid function return before completed request

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I have an array of string (id) and I need to iterate on it to make an ajax request to an api and push response in an array. The problem is that, because of asynchronous load, the return statement is made before the end of the call.
Here an example:

```
getArrConcat: function (id) {
    var arr = new Array();
    var arrJoin = "";
    for (var i=0; i<id.length; i++){
        Model.load(id[i], {
            success: function (org) {
                arr.push(org.data);
            }
        });
    }
    arrJoin = arr.join('; ');
    return arrJoin;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute `getArrConcat` synchronously when the result depends on an ajax request.

The easiest solution would be to make `getArrConcat` returning a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and make the calling function [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

This would look more or less like:

```
getArrConcat: function (id) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        for (var i=0; i<id.length; i++){
            Model.load(id[i], {
                success: function (org) {
                    var arr = new Array();
                    var arrJoin = "";
                    arr.push(org.data);
                    arrJoin = arr.join('; ');
                    resolve(arrJoin);
                }
            });
        }
    });
},

// call from an async method:
callGetArrConcat: async function() {
    const concatString = await this.getArrConcat(123);
    //Do something with concatString
}
```

Comment: can I use async function in extjs?

Comment: Generally yes. During development you need a browser that supports async functions (all recent browsers do). A recent Sencha CMD Version is able to transpile Promises and async functions to support older browsers as well (it might print something like this during build: `JavaScript input level is NEXT and output level is ES5`).

Comment: Please see here for reference (Sencha CMD 6.5 Changelog): https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.0.0/guides/whats_new_cmd65.html#whats_new_cmd65_-_beyond_es6